# Apache zeppelin build process failure in zeppelin-web with bower

Tags: maven, build, installation, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build zeppelin locally with windows and babun/cygwin. [This site](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2015/04/building-zeppelin-in-windows-8.html) got me headed in the right direction, but I run into the following error when the build gets to Web Application:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 8) -> [Help 1]
```

I can go into the `zeppelin-web` directory and run `bower install` successfully, but I'm not sure where to go from here? If I try to do `mvn install -DskipTests`, it tries to run the `bower` command again.

If I try to "move on" and attempt to build under `../zeppelin-server` it will say that it can't find the `zeppelin-web` dependency.

I think I would like to run `bower install` manually, as suggested by the site above, but I'm not sure where to go from there? Is it possible to pick up `mvn` where it left off? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. First try to go to the zeppeling-web component and run there mvn package -DskipTests. It should give you more details about what is failing:

```
cd zeppelin-web
mvn package -DskipTests
```

In my case it was a problem with git proxies, since I am working in a corporate environment. At the console, issuing the command:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, did it for me as well

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the build command with `sudo`

Comment: even with sudo, the same results are observed in my case. `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" mvn clean package -Pspark-1.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 -DskipTests`

Comment: I did; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254847/issues-installing-zeppelin-on-centos-6-with-vagrant is the open issue I have with more details.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: run the following as a non-root user, (replace <goals> with your -P and -D flags, or remove for standalone install):

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" mvn clean install <goals> -DskipTests
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" mvn clean install <goals> -DskipTests -rf :zeppelin-web
```