# Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed

Tags: maven, bower, bower-install, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build Apache zeppelin from the source code. But it breaks at the **"zeppelin-web"** with the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 8) -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the full debug log.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 8) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.BowerMojo.execute(BowerMojo.java:41)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 8)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:38)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.BowerMojo.execute(BowerMojo.java:39)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I found and tried these solutions on the web but any of them couldn't solve the issue.

[Apache zeppelin build process failure in zeppelin-web with bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084106/apache-zeppelin-build-process-failure-in-zeppelin-web-with-bower)
http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2015/04/building-zeppelin-in-windows-8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same problem here, and this answer is just a guide, for those who are getting the same error:
The maven output was similar to yours:

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]**

but going up a little bit it showed:

**[ERROR] bower                                      ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular**

This means that bower was been executed but it couldn't choose between some available angular versions.
To fix that I have gone to 
/zeppeling-root-folder/zeppelin-web
and executed

```
./bower install
```

At the end of bower install it asked me to choose between one of the available angular versions, which I choose 1.5.0, after it just run a

```
npm install node-gyp@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with apache zeppelin master branch. Now it is rectified. Just get the latest master branch and try build it

Comment: Still happening here