# Zeppelin: web Application failure while building zeppelin

Tags: node.js, maven, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build apache zeppelin using the instructions in this tutorial : [Installing Zeppelig Tutorial](https://trevorgrant.org/2015/11/03/apache-casserole-a-delicious-big-data-recipe-for-the-whole-family/)

I installed spark 2.0 and maven 3.3.9 the latest versions. I used the following command to build zeppelin:

```
sudo mvn clean package -DskipTests -Psparkr -Ppyspark -Pspark-2.0 -Dflink
```

I got this error:

```
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency /home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin

/zeppelin-web/node_modules/grunt-jscs/node_modules/jscs requires lodash@'~3.10.0' but will load
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency /home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/grunt-jscs/node_modules/lodash,
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.6.1
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency /home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma-coverage/node_modules/istanbul/node_modules/handlebars requires source-map@'^0.4.4' but will load
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency /home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma-coverage/node_modules/source-map,
[ERROR] npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.6
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:bower (bower install) @ zeppelin-web ---
[INFO] Running 'bower --allow-root install' in /home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web
[ERROR] module.js:338
[ERROR]     throw err;
[ERROR]           ^
[ERROR] Error: Cannot find module 'q'
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
[ERROR]     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
[ERROR]     at require (module.js:384:17)
[ERROR]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:6:9)
[ERROR]     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
[ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
[ERROR]     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.333 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [ 12.493 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [  7.460 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Display system apis ...................... SUCCESS [ 16.886 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [ 33.212 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [ 25.951 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  0.387 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  0.223 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  0.287 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Livy interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  0.520 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: HBase interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  3.979 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  0.488 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: JDBC interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  0.694 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: File System Interpreters ................. SUCCESS [  0.766 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SUCCESS [  7.653 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  0.871 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  0.334 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Python interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [  0.337 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  2.984 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Cassandra interpreter ............. SUCCESS [01:00 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  6.269 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: BigQuery interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  0.833 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Alluxio interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  3.350 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [  3.653 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-06T19:09:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 164M/479M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

There is another thread on stackoverflow with the same error and @dirceusemighini suggests to cd to zeppelin-web and run the following command. The reason i created another question is because i am a new stack user and it wont let me comment to that question.

```
./bower install
```

I have tried that and i got the following error:

```
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/parallels/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
parallels@ubuntu:~/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web$
```

I have already unistall node, nodejs and npm and i reinstalled them globally

node -v : 5.0.0

npm -v  : 3.3.6

bower -v: 1.7.9

Any suggestions??

Comment: This is on a VM running Ubuntu 14.04 yes? 

Could you update with the linkback to the other question you referenced, pls.

Also, the error has something to do with `allow-root-install` could you try building with out root and see what happens / post the results. You may need to clone in to an entirely new directory.  Also remove `-Dflink` from your build command as that is not doing anything.

Comment: Also did you try [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/pluralsight-gulp/issues/7)
`npm install -g q`

Comment: Yes thats correct. I have tried `npm install -g q` and nothing changes.

Comment: Here is the link of the post that i referenced(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014273/failed-to-run-task-bower-allow-root-install-failed) 
When i run the code without sudo it fails from the first line of Reactor Summurry which is Zeppelin ........... (look from the original error on the post)
Even when i remove `-Dflink` i still get the same error from the post

I cant post the full errors here

Comment: after you updated your env, did you delete zeppelin directory and reclone (that would be the next thing I'd try)

Comment: to be honest, i formatted Ubuntu today and installed everything again. Still got the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was Maven installation.  I uninstall Maven and i reinstall it manually to `/usr/local/apache-maven/`
Then using a text editor i set the environment variables and re-run the build. Build was successful now. I don't know the actual cause of that but at the end it works..

```
gedit  ~/.bashrc

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Run the build:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```